# Getting something weird in my jsp code, x++ doesn't working

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

My looping was working fine, but the value of x variable in jsp doesn't change.

```
function divProductVisible(elem){
                var div = document.getElementById('linkHD');
                var divProduct = document.getElementById('linkProduct');
                div.style.visibility = 'visible';
                divProduct.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                var linkHD = elem.innerHTML;
                var x =3;
                var y;
                var i;
                <% int x= 0;%>
                alert(<%=x%>);
                for(i = 0; i < x ;i++){
                    <% dataProduct1 = daftarProduct1[x]; x++;%>
                            alert(<%=x%>);

                }  
            }
```

but, this code is working fine

```
function divHDVisible(elem){
            var div = document.getElementById('linkHD');
            var divProduct = document.getElementById('linkProduct');
            div.style.visibility = 'visible';
            divProduct.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            var linkHD = elem.innerHTML;
            var x =<%=daftarJobs1.length%>;
            var y;
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < x ;i++){
                <% dataJobs1 = daftarJobs1[x]; x++;%>
                if(linkHD.toString() == <%=dataJobs1.getID_Harware_Use()%>){
                <%
                idTT = dataJobs1.getID_Harware_Use();
                %>
            }
            }
            alert(<%=x%>);
        }
```

Both of the methods were in the same page and the output is must be same.

Comment: What are you seeing here alert(<%=x%>)

Comment: the end value of variable x, there are 2 x variable, one in java n another one for javascript

Comment: I don't see how the second block can work (compile), since the *server-size* `x` is undefined. Remember, anything inside `<%  %>` is executed server-side, and everything else if executed client-side (browser).

Answer (score 0):

*I'll assume the two blocks are in the same JSP file.*

To a JSP, anything outside `<% %>` is just text, so for actual execution it just sees:

```
text
<% int x= 0;%>
text<%=x%>text
text
<% dataProduct1 = daftarProduct1[x]; x++;%>
text<%=x%>text
text

text
text<%=daftarJobs1.length%>text
text
<% dataJobs1 = daftarJobs1[x]; x++;%>
text<%=dataJobs1.getID_Harware_Use()%>text
<% idTT = dataJobs1.getID_Harware_Use(); %>
text
text<%=x%>text
text
```

---

Executed, that becomes:

```
text
text0text
text
text1text
text

text
text3text
text
text999text
text
text2text
text
```

where `999` is the value of `daftarJobs1[1].getID_Harware_Use()`.

---

So second block failed to compile. First block became:

```
function divProductVisible(elem){
    var div = document.getElementById('linkHD');
    var divProduct = document.getElementById('linkProduct');
    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
    divProduct.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var linkHD = elem.innerHTML;
    var x =3;
    var y;
    var i;
    alert(0);
    for(i = 0; i < x ;i++){
        alert(1);
    }  
}

function divHDVisible(elem){
    var div = document.getElementById('linkHD');
    var divProduct = document.getElementById('linkProduct');
    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
    divProduct.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var linkHD = elem.innerHTML;
    var x =3;
    var y;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < x ;i++){
        if(linkHD.toString() == 999){
        }
    }
    alert(2);
}
```

So, which one did what you expected it to do?

Comment: thanks to try, yeah, its not what i want, the case was, i want get data from database by clicking a link, n show up in the same page, not link to another page. Can u help me with this case?

Comment: Not really, because that has *nothing* to do with this question, but you have two choices: 1) Re-display the entire page with a query parameter that makes server include the information you want. 2) Use AJAX to query the server for the data and dynamically update the page. --- Both are way out of scope for this question, so don't bother asking. Create a new question if needed.